# Gridview group similar rows in one

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, which is bound to a table in a database using `EntityDataSource`. I populate the gridview only with the items in the db which correspond to the where clause.

```
FRUIT       COLOR   NUMB.SEEDS
ORANGE      ORANGE  3
APPLE       RED     4
ORANGE      ORANGE  2
STRAWBERRY  RED     0
```

What I want is to sum the similar rows with respect to NUMB.SEEDS, like this:

```
FRUIT       COLOR   NUMB.SEEDS
ORANGE      ORANGE  5
APPLE       RED     4
STRAWBERRY  RED     0
```

Some hint please? I don't know where to begin.

This is where I put the where clause:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="MyEfDataSource"
    runat="server" ContextTypeName="MyContext"
    EntitySetName="Fruits" EntityTypeFilter="Fruit"
    AutoPage="true" AutoSort="true" Where="it.idName = @idName">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlFruit" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" Name="idName" />
    </WhereParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: did you write your where clause in LINQ ? if yes - could you please show them here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SQL, you would use a `GROUP BY` clause.  I think this should work in the `EntityDataSource`:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="MyEfDataSource"
    runat="server" ContextTypeName="MyContext"
    EntitySetName="Fruits" EntityTypeFilter="Fruit"
    AutoPage="true" AutoSort="true" 
    Select="it.FRUIT, it.COLOR, SUM(it.[NUMB.SEEDS])"
    Where="it.idName = @idName"
    GroupBy"it.FRUIT, it.COLOR" >
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlFruit" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" Name="idName" />
    </WhereParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

*Note that I'm calling your fields in the "Select" and "Where" expressions based on the columns you put in your question.  They may be different in your actual data source.*

Comment: In select="...", should I write every field that appears in my datasource?

Comment: @Camilla Just the ones that you want to show up in your `GridView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `QueryCreated` event.

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=AdventureWorksEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="AdventureWorksEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="FRUITS" 
    onquerycreated="EntityDataSource1_QueryCreated">
</asp:EntityDataSource>

protected void EntityDataSource1_QueryCreated(object sender, QueryCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    var fruits = e.Query.Cast<Fruits>();
    e.Query = fruits.GroupBy(fruit => fruit.COLOR)
                     .Select(group => new { FRUIT, COLOR,   group.Sum(fruit => fruit.SEEDS)});;  
}
```

Refer: [Applying LINQ Queries to EntityDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404748%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)